# Corrupt, but working HDD

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NTFS Partition Repair - Recommendations](https://superuser.com/questions/38181/ntfs-partition-repair-recommendations)

I struggled to describe this, so excuse the ambiguous title. I have an old Western Digital Caviar 120Gb HDD I found out - I suspect it's the contents of an old PC of mine so it's bound to have photos or something I'd want hence I'm being quite careful about what I do to it.

Firstly, it's an IDE drive and I've got a USB -> IDE converter. I don't have anything else to try it with, but I have 15 other drives here which have all worked fine including another of the same type.

The drive would have been mounted with XP and is NTFS.

Firstly, when I plug it into Windows 7 I get an "Invalid Disk" error in Disk Management. I followed the procedure here:

http://www.neondemon.com/archives/how-to-fix-invalid-disk-error-in-windows-7

And got the disc to read. However, the 'data' is garbled. I reset the changes and fired up Ubuntu. The disc mounts fine, but shows the 'data' in exactly the same method. Here is what it looks like:

(NB: All the 'files' show as 216Mb)

[image: Disk1]

[image: Disk2]

I then ran this utility:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

But it seemed happy enough with the single partition on there.

I'm very iffy about doing much else as there's no way to know if it's a fix until I've written back to the drive. I should do a byte by byte copy, but I don't think I have the space so I was hoping someone could give me a bit of a pointer.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that, because this isn't a corrupt volume at all.  It _was_ a "dynamic disc" container partition, that could potentially contain anything from portions of multiple spanned volumes to every Nth stripe of a striped volume, that's been turned into an _MS Data_ "basic disc" partition by the questioner manually editing the partition type in the partition table.  Of course it won't be readable.  The advice on Mike Norman's web-log is very poor advice, because it _only_ "works" for people who don't use _any_ form of striping or spanning _at all_ on their dynamic discs.

Comment: Interesting point JdeBP - I don't think I used it in RAID, but it's not out of the realms of possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Corrupt data table for NTFS?
This may be your friend.
http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm

Comment: Perhaps explain why that link will be of use to him (us)?